# Pass objects to application from HttpModule

Tags: asp.net, .net, httpmodule

Is there a way to create objects in HTTP module and pass those objects to applications.

I can use [HTTPContext.Items](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.items(v=vs.110).aspx).  But that means I will reference System.Web in any DLL in the application that will use those data.  Utility.dll is reading data generated by the http module, and I don't want to reference System.Web in that DLL because it is used by both web and desktop applications.
of course Desktop applications will not find the object, this is not a problem.

Comment: `HTTPContext.Items` is the most common way of doing it. Implementing HTTP module in ASP.NET requires `System.Web`, so what is the reason for trying to avoid it?

Comment: So you want to work with HTTP module, but without System.Web? In this case you can use raw sockets, they are located in System.dll

Comment: @dotnetom,  A utility DLL is reading data generated by the module, I don't want to reference System.Web in that DLL, because it is used by both web and desktop applications.  I wish to pass an object to the application, where that object does not belong to System.Web.

Comment: What is your objection to setting a reference to System.Web in a desktop application? A Desktop application can use it just fine.

Comment: @Costa How about serializing the object to XML and deserialize it back in your app to the object you wish to work with?

Comment: I think you should provide more information: how do you want to pass an object (via memory, http, etc)? What are the problems with using web.dll (unwanted exceptions or module referencing perfectionism)?

Comment: @Siva Gopal, I cannot do that the module should be very light.

Comment: How about you define an interface in `Utility.dll`. Then have `Utility.dll` use an instance of the interface when it needs to fetch data. Then implement the interface in the web application and have the implementation fetch what you need from `HTTPContext.Items`. Would this work?

Comment: @user1429080, I thought about that but I had a problem in wiring-up.
but JUST now, I got an idea, I can do the wiring up in Application start at global.asax, I will try this, that suppose to work.

Comment: It seems this is a classical case to use Dependency Injection. You need to pass your data to `Utility` classes in constructors or setters. You shouldn't do it in `HttpModule`. Let the module accumulate data, and store it in `HttpContext` Items. Pass the data later inside base Page (or Controller, if you're using MVC).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @user1429080.  it is kind of simple DI pattern.

Add an interface to Util.dll.
Add a reference to it in class Util add a property to access it.

The interface is implemented in WebUtil.dll.  WebUtil is referencing System.Web.

In HttpModule.Init() I assign the implementation to the interface.

Util class is using the interface to read data generated from HttpModule instead of accessing System.Web.

Now I can have another source of data by creating another implementation for the interface.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the new and extensible cache API in System.Runtime.Caching, namely, the MemoryCache class. Just use a shared constant as the name and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

I think your web module should communicate with Utility.dll and not the other way around. It should call a function inside Utility.dll with the data it needs. Since we don't know much about the nature of your application and that you didn't provide much information about how you want your different modules to communicate, it hard to give a definite answer.

The Utility.dll module could have a method accepting data like

`public void QueueProcessingData(YourDataType[] data) {/* ... */}`

If you really want your Utility.dll module to pull data from the web server, then you could use the builtin cache like @Ricardo Peres said. Example of using the builtin MemoryCache:

```
var data = "object your web module created and you want to pass to utility.dll";
ObjectCache cache = MemoryCache.Default;
cache.Add("The name you want", data, new CacheItemPolicy { AbsoluteExpiration = DateTime.MaxValue });
```

That way your other modules don't have to reference System.Web

Answer (score 0):

`HttpContext.Items` is an `IDictionary`, so you can avoid a System.Web dependency in your common code by depending on that abstraction:

#### Utility.dll

```
class Util
{
    static void DoStuff(IDictionary environment) { ... }
}
```

#### App.dll

```
class App
{
    void DoStuff()
    {
        Util.DoStuff(new Hashtable { { "Foo", "Bar" } });
    }
}
```

#### Web.dll

```
class MyModule : IHttpModule
{
    void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        Util.DoStuff(context.Context.Items);
    }
}
```

Comment: I cannot do this because I cannot add overload in util.  I need other modules in the web application to use DoStuff transparently.  But thanks anyway.